# State an antiderivative $F: D \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ or explain why an antiderivative does not exist.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

State an antiderivative $F: D \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ or explain why an antiderivative does not exist.

a) $f(z) = z^2 , D = \mathbb{C}$

b) $f(z) = z \sin z,  D = \mathbb{C}$

c) $f(z) = |z|^2 , D = \mathbb{C}$

d) $f(z) = \overline{z} , D = \mathbb{C}$

For a) and b) I just performed simple integration for the equations

a)$ z^3/3 + C$ and b) $-z\cos z + \sin z +C$

but I am stuck on c) and d). It seems like an antiderivative does not exist but how do i explain that?

Answer (score 4):

If $F: D \to \Bbb C$ is complex differentiable at all points of $D$ then it is a holomorphic function in $D$, and its derivative $F'$ is holomorphic in $D$ as well. (That is a consequence of, e.g., [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem), and implies that $F$ is infinitely often complex differentiable.)

You can verify (e.g. with the Cauchy-Riemann equations) that the functions $f$ in (c) and (d) are not holomorphic, and therefore not the derivative of a holomorphic function $F$.

The restriction $D = \Bbb C$ is irrelevant in these cases, $f(z) = |z|^2$ and $f(z) = \overline z$ are not holomophic in any open subset $D \subset \Bbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

If an antiderivative exists, then $f$ must be holomorphic. But your functions in c) and d) are not because they do not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.